# swipeToDeleteCallback change to beleft to right - Kotlin Android

Tags: android, kotlin

I have this code which works perfectly by swiping right to left on Recyclerview items to delete
but I need to change it to left to right

Can you please change it to LTR because I tried It didn't work for me

```
abstract class SwipeToDeleteCallback(context: Context) : ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback(0, ItemTouchHelper.LEFT){

    private val deleteIcon = ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.ic_delete_white_24)
    private val intrinsicWidth = deleteIcon?.intrinsicWidth
    private val intrinsicHeight = deleteIcon?.intrinsicHeight
    //private val background = ColorDrawable()
    private val background = GradientDrawable()
    private val color = ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.swipe_delete_color)
    //private val backgroundColor = Color.parseColor("#f44336")
    private val clearPaint = Paint().apply { xfermode = PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR) }

    override fun onMove(
        recyclerView: RecyclerView,
        viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder,
        target: RecyclerView.ViewHolder
    ): Boolean {
        return false
    }

    override fun onChildDraw(
        c: Canvas,
        recyclerView: RecyclerView,
        viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder,
        dX: Float,
        dY: Float,
        actionState: Int,
        isCurrentlyActive: Boolean
    ) {
        val itemView = viewHolder.itemView
        val itemHeight = itemView.bottom - itemView.top
        val isCanceled = dX == 0f && !isCurrentlyActive

        if (isCanceled) {
            clearCanvas(c, itemView.right + dX, itemView.top.toFloat(), itemView.right.toFloat(), itemView.bottom.toFloat())
            super.onChildDraw(c, recyclerView, viewHolder, dX, dY, actionState, isCurrentlyActive)
            return
        }
        // Draw the red delete background
        //background.color = this.color
        background.setColor(this.color)
        background.setBounds(itemView.right + dX.toInt(), itemView.top, itemView.right, itemView.bottom)
        background.cornerRadius = 20.0f
        background.draw(c)
        // Calculate position of delete icon
        val deleteIconTop = itemView.top + (itemHeight - intrinsicHeight!!) / 2
        val deleteIconMargin = (itemHeight - intrinsicHeight) / 2
        val deleteIconLeft = itemView.right - deleteIconMargin - intrinsicWidth!!
        val deleteIconRight = itemView.right - deleteIconMargin
        val deleteIconBottom = deleteIconTop + intrinsicHeight

        // Draw the delete icon
        deleteIcon?.setBounds(deleteIconLeft, deleteIconTop, deleteIconRight, deleteIconBottom)
        deleteIcon?.draw(c)

        super.onChildDraw(c, recyclerView, viewHolder, dX, dY, actionState, isCurrentlyActive)

    }


    private fun clearCanvas(c: Canvas?, left: Float, top: Float, right: Float, bottom: Float) {
        c?.drawRect(left, top, right, bottom, clearPaint)
    }
}
```

and this is the implmentation for it MainActivity which works fine
if you can change it to LTR or add parameter to it to detect which swipe direction and make it work

```
 val swipeHandler = object : SwipeToDeleteCallbackLTR(this) {
                override fun onSwiped(viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, direction: Int) {
                    val adapter1 = recyclerView.adapter as StockCompanyListAdapter
                    adapter1.removeAt(viewHolder.adapterPosition)
                }
            
            var itemTouchHelper = ItemTouchHelper(swipeHandler)
            itemTouchHelper.attachToRecyclerView(recyclerView)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `ItemTouchHelper.LEFT` to `ItemTouchHelper.RIGHT` in ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback and adjust icon

```
abstract class SwipeToDeleteCallback(
    context: Context
) : ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback(0, ItemTouchHelper.RIGHT) {
    private val deleteIcon = ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.ic_delete_white_24)
    private val intrinsicWidth = deleteIcon?.intrinsicWidth
    private val intrinsicHeight = deleteIcon?.intrinsicHeight

    //private val background = ColorDrawable()
    private val background = GradientDrawable()
    private val color = ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.swipe_delete_color)

    //private val backgroundColor = Color.parseColor("#f44336")
    private val clearPaint = Paint().apply { xfermode = PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR) }

    override fun onMove(
        recyclerView: RecyclerView,
        viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder,
        target: RecyclerView.ViewHolder,
    ): Boolean {
        return false
    }

    override fun onChildDraw(
        c: Canvas,
        recyclerView: RecyclerView,
        viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder,
        dX: Float,
        dY: Float,
        actionState: Int,
        isCurrentlyActive: Boolean,
    ) {
        val itemView = viewHolder.itemView
        val itemHeight = itemView.bottom - itemView.top
        val isCanceled = dX == 0f && !isCurrentlyActive

        if (isCanceled) {
            clearCanvas(
                c,
                itemView.left.toFloat(),
                itemView.top.toFloat(),
                itemView.left + dX,
                itemView.bottom.toFloat()
            )
            super.onChildDraw(c, recyclerView, viewHolder, dX, dY, actionState, false)
            return
        }
        // Draw the red delete background
        //background.color = this.color
        background.setColor(this.color)
        background.setBounds(
            itemView.left,
            itemView.top,
            itemView.left + dX.toInt(),
            itemView.bottom
        )
        background.cornerRadius = 20.0f
        background.draw(c)
        // Calculate position of delete icon
        val deleteIconTop = itemView.top + (itemHeight - intrinsicHeight!!) / 2
        val deleteIconMargin = (itemHeight - intrinsicHeight) / 2
        val deleteIconLeft = itemView.left + deleteIconMargin
        val deleteIconRight = deleteIconLeft + intrinsicWidth!!
        val deleteIconBottom = deleteIconTop + intrinsicHeight

        // Draw the delete icon
        deleteIcon?.setBounds(deleteIconLeft, deleteIconTop, deleteIconRight, deleteIconBottom)
        deleteIcon?.draw(c)

        super.onChildDraw(c, recyclerView, viewHolder, dX, dY, actionState, isCurrentlyActive)

    }


    private fun clearCanvas(c: Canvas?, left: Float, top: Float, right: Float, bottom: Float) {
        c?.drawRect(left, top, right, bottom, clearPaint)
    }
}
```

Comment: This is only part of solution. It will swipe left to right but red delete button is not shown